# Finding the OPE coefficients when the correlator and block decomposition is given

Tags: quantum-field-theory, computational-physics, conformal-field-theory

I have the following expression which arises while studying minimal models in CFT. The 4-point amplitude of scalars is given by

$$G(z,\overline{z}) = ((1-z)(1-\overline{z}))^{\frac{m-1}{m+1}}\mathcal{H}\bigg(\frac{1}{m+1}, \frac{m}{m+1}, \frac{2}{m+1}\bigg) - \\
\frac{\Gamma^2\big(\frac{2}{m+1}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{2}{m+1}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{2m-1}{m+1}\big)((z-1)(\overline{z}-1))^{\frac{m-1}{m+1}}(z\overline{z})^{\frac{m-1}{m+1}}}{\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{m+1}\big)\Gamma^2\big(\frac{2m}{m+1}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{2-m}{m+1}\big)}\mathcal{H}\bigg(\frac{m}{m+1},\frac{2-m}{m+1},\frac{2m}{m+1}\bigg)
$$
which takes values $m = 3, 4, 5, \cdots$ etc. for various unitary minimal models. The function $\mathcal{H}$ is given by
$$\mathcal{H}(a,b,c) = F(a,b,c,z)F(a,b,c,\overline{z})$$ where $F$ is `Hypergeometric2F1`. I can decompose this $G(z,\overline{z})$ as
$$ G(z, \overline{z}) = (1-z)^{\frac{m-1}{m+1}}(1-\overline{z})^{\frac{m-1}{m+1}} \sum_{\Delta, \ell}c_{\Delta, \ell} g_{\Delta, \ell}(z, \overline{z})$$,
where the functions $g_{\Delta, \ell}$ are given by
$$g_{\Delta, \ell} = \frac{k_{\Delta + \ell}(z)k_{\Delta-\ell}(\overline{z}) + k_{\Delta+\ell}(\overline{z}) k_{\Delta - \ell}(z)}{\delta_{0,\ell} + 1}$$

where in turn the $k$ are defined as
$$k_a(x) = x^{a/2}F(a/2, a/2, a, x)$$

I want to obtain the coefficients $c_{\Delta,\ell}$ for a given $m$. Right now I would be happy if I can obtain it for $m = 4$. I have the coefficients for $m = 3$ but I haven't figured out how to obtain them for $m = 4$. I am trying to do this using $\texttt{Mathematica}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't get any answers here, you may want to try over at [mathematica.se]

Comment: How does the value of $m$ change the difficulty of this? You can always find the low-lying coefficients recursively by brute force. Do you mean that guessing a general formula from this data is too hard unless $m = 3$? In any case, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.06622